# How should I initialize my network with Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

My code is a simple Sequential network like:

```
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(s_dim, 256),
            nn.Softplus(),
            nn.Linear(256, 256),
            nn.Softplus(),
            nn.Linear(256, a_dim)
        )
```

I want to initialize the weights of every layer, and make them follow the Normal distribution with (0,1).

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-initialize-weights-in-nn-sequential-container/8534

Comment: I would strongly suggest not to initialize your network's weights this way. Doing so may make it much more difficult to get your model to converge. pytorch already has a good default weight initializaiton heuristic that takes into account the structure of your model.

Comment: yeah, what you said is right, and Pytorch already has a good default weight.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the nn.Sequential and initialize each linear layer using normal (gaussian) distribution. The sample code are as follows:

```
# this method can be defined outside your model class
def weights_init(m):
    if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
        torch.nn.init.normal_(m.weight, mean=0.0, std=1.0)
        torch.nn.init.zero_(m.bias)

# define init method inside your model class
def init_with_normal(self):
    self.net.apply(weights_init)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try the way you suggested!